# Subsonic 3.0 Bug?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, subsonic3

I have a table named "data_buckets" and a column in that table named "data_bucket".
When I buid the activerecord.cs, subsonic created a class name "data_bucket" (extending IActiveRecord) for the table and obviously a conflict will arise when you try to access the field "data_bucket". Is it a known issue? Is there any workaround without having to rename the table or the column?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: end all table names in an s, or edit subsonic and take out plurolise ??? something like that.... also handy to know is name your primary key  TableName, with s stripped of and ID, i.e tables Users, the primary key is UserID

Comment: @minus4: Plural has nothing to do with it, and you don't need to follow that convention for primary key columns, SubSonic reads the table's metadata to determine which column is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Settings.ttinclude template file for SubSonic and modify the `string CleanUp(string tableName)` function.

Despite the function's name, more than just table names will get passed through it (procedure names, procedure argument names, table column names, etc).

You can do whatever renaming's you need, like removing underscores.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered similar problem. I think that renaming of the column is only way to fix it.